# How to reference "cells" within a column in R?

Tags: r, formula, array-formulas, r-table

I'm trying to calculate numeric ranges based on the moving average of a column of data. I have found a way to use `caTools::runmean` to produce a column of moving averages, and I know how to work with this in Excel to produce the columns I want, but I would love to know a way to do all of this in one R script.

Here is my simplified reproducible example for R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caTools)
data <- as_tibble(data.frame(
  Index = as.integer(c(18,19,21,22,23,25,26,29)),
  mydbl = c(8.905,13.31,15.739,17.544,19.054,20.393,21.623,22.764)))

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(avg = runmean(mydbl,
                       k = 2,
                       alg = "exact",
                       endrule = "NA"))
```

This tibble will look like this:

```
> data
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Index mydbl   avg
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    18  8.90  NA  
2    19 13.3   11.1
3    21 15.7   14.5
4    22 17.5   16.6
5    23 19.1   18.3
6    25 20.4   19.7
7    26 21.6   21.0
8    29 22.8   22.2
```

To produce the remaining data I want, I exported this to Excel with `write_csv(data,...)` and the final table is shown below. The first value in `dbl_i` is the formula `=B2-ABS(C3-B2)` (the difference between `mydbl` and the next `avg` subtracted from `mydbl` to create an equidistant lower limit). The last value in `dbl_f` is the formula `=B9+ABS(C9-B9)` (the difference between `mydbl` and the `avg` added to `mydbl` to create an equidistant upper limit). The other values in the two columns are just direct references to the `avg` column.

```
Index   mydbl   avg     dbl_i   dbl_f
18      8.905   NA      6.7025  11.1075
19      13.31   11.1075 11.1075 14.5245
21      15.739  14.5245 14.5245 16.6415
22      17.544  16.6415 16.6415 18.299
23      19.054  18.299  18.299  19.7235
25      20.393  19.7235 19.7235 21.008
26      21.623  21.008  21.008  22.1935
29      22.764  22.1935 22.1935 23.3345
```

Yes, the `dbl_i` is just the `avg` column but with the first value being `=B2-abs(C3-B2)`. And the `dbl_f` column is the same as the `avg` column except it's moved up one, and the final value is `=B9+abs(C9=B9)`. Ultimately it seems the real problem lies in finding a way to reproduce the Excel calculations `D2=B2-ABS(C3-B2)` and `E9=B9+ABS(C9-B9)`.

Does anyone know how they would reproduce these calculations in R? I was looking for a way to create a formula in R that could be the equivalent of `B2-ABS(C3-B2)`, but could not find one, unless I create a matrix instead. Do I have to create a matrix?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: perhaps something like `dbl_i = head(data[,"mydbl"],-1) - (data[-1,"avg"] - head(data[,"mydbl"],-1))`

Comment: EIther do `data$avg <- runmean(data$mydbl, ...)` or `data %>% mutate(avg=runmean(mydbl,...))`, you should not use `data$mydbl` inside `mutate`.

Comment: Are you sure the desired output is correct? The columns avg and `dbl_i` are identical after the first row. Is that what you want? and the formula for `dbl_f` seems to be `mydbl+ABS(avg -mydbl )`? Is that right? Then how is the first value not NA because you have an NA in the first avg column.

Comment: @MrFlick, the dbl_i and dbl_f columns are the same except offset by one, making two values different. The actual cell formulas for `dbl_i` are `=B2-ABS(C3-B2)` and then `C3`, `C4`, etc. Then `dbl_f` is `C3` to `C9` and finally `=B9+ABS(C9-B9)`.

Comment: @r2evans Okay, thanks! Changing it in the reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    avg = zoo::rollmean(mydbl, 2, align="right", fill=NA),
    dbl_i = if_else(row_number() == 1L, mydbl - abs(lead(avg) - mydbl), avg),
    dbl_f = if_else(row_number() == n(), mydbl + abs(avg - mydbl), lead(avg))
  )
# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#   Index mydbl   avg dbl_i dbl_f
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    18  8.90  NA    6.70  11.1
# 2    19 13.3   11.1 11.1   14.5
# 3    21 15.7   14.5 14.5   16.6
# 4    22 17.5   16.6 16.6   18.3
# 5    23 19.1   18.3 18.3   19.7
# 6    25 20.4   19.7 19.7   21.0
# 7    26 21.6   21.0 21.0   22.2
# 8    29 22.8   22.2 22.2   23.3
```

Honestly it's not the most elegant, but it gets the job done.

(BTW: I'm using `zoo::rollmean` because I don't have `caTools` installed, but it's the same effect I believe.)

Comment: I think this works! I just changed `dbl_f = if_else(row_number() == n(), mydbl + abs(avg - mydbl), lead(avg))` (changed `lag(mydbl)` to just `mydbl`). Somehow both came out with 23.3345 in the final row of `dbl_f`. But I think it gave me what I wanted!

Thanks so much! Out of curiosity, why does `row_number() == 1L` need the `L`?

Comment: Yup, my bad, changed in the code. I like it in order to be explicit, it will work without it. Many programming languages require you to compare type-with-type, so that a "double" will not compare with an "integer". R is much more forgiving, but that can bite you ([R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)). In this vein, many functions in the `tidyverse` (`purrr` specifically) mandate class-explicitness. I like to be clear in what I am expecting, and row numbers should always be integers (ergo the trailing `L`).

Comment: Note that `rollmeanr` with an r on the end defaults to `align = "right"` .